# Override the Add method of a ComboBox

Tags: c#, windows

Is there a way to override the Add() method of Combobx?

The reason I ask this is that I want to Add the class objects to my combbox but for display I want it to show the Name of my objects.

so for example:  `combbox.Items.Add(myClassObject)`

but what we actually see in the combbobx as the user will show as `myClassObject.Name`

Comment: You've received several completely different, valid solutions. Ain't programming cool?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I right understood your request, you can do that using the binding:

Pseudocode:

```
comboBox.DataSource = collectionOfData;
comboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

The data will be added to combo but *visualized* will be the `Name` property of the "data".

This all done using [DisplayMember Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Because `ComboBox` uses `ToString()` method of object which is added in Items collections to display on the UI, so override `ToString` of `myClassObject` to return whatever you want, it is simple:

```
class myClassObject
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "whatever you want";
    }
}
```

With this way you do not touch ComboBox Control

Answer (score 3):

You can develop `extension Method`

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static void Add(this ComboBox, myClassObject value)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The existing ComboBox class is designed to already do what the OP needs, he just needs to use it correctly.

Comment: @BDotA know very well, we are on a possibility of personalized behavior

Answer (score 0):

Create a new control that extends combobox control. 
Then override `Add` method.

Comment: The existing `ComboBox` class is designed to already do what the OP needs, he just needs to use it correctly.